# How to serialize additional edge information in QuickGraph?

Tags: serialization, quickgraph

I'm working with a graph dataset that could have edges of different logical meaning, like that:

```
"Bavaria" -[PART_OF]-> "Germany"
"Germany" -[NEIGHBOR_OF]-> "France"
```

I represent this domain by using the `QuickGraph.TaggedEdge` where `TTag` generic parameter is a `string`:

```
QuickGraph.BidirectionalGraph<IGeographicalUnit, TaggedEdge<IGeographicalUnit, string>>
```

This works perfectly until the moment I try to serialize my graph to `.graphml` form:

```
using (var w = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Temp\data.graphml"))
{
    _graph.SerializeToGraphML<IGeographicalUnit, TaggedEdge<IGeographicalUnit, string>, BidirectionalGraph<IGeographicalUnit, TaggedEdge<IGeographicalUnit, string>>>(w);
}
```

Serialized edge data doesn't contain any tag information, only source and target:

```
<edge id="0" source="0" target="1" />
```

What I want is something like:

```
<edge id="0" source="0" target="1" tag="PART_OF" />
```

So, the question is, how can I enforce this tag to be serialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I created my own edge implementation pretty similar to the `TaggedEdge` mentioned above:

```
public class DataEdge<TVertex> : Edge<TVertex>
{
    [XmlAttribute("Tag")]
    public string Tag { get; set; }

    public DataEdge(TVertex source, TVertex target)
        : base(source, target) { }

    public DataEdge(TVertex source, TVertex target, string tag)
        : this(source, target)
    {
        Tag = tag;
    }
}
```

Then I replaced `TaggedEdge` occurrences with my `DataEdge`. After that, serialization produced the following XML output:

```
<edge id="0" source="0" target="1">
  <data key="Tag">PART_OF</data>
</edge>
```

The problem is solved, but I hope that another solution exists that don't involve writing your own `Edge` implementations.